# java reference libraries while copying and importing projects

Tags: eclipse

A java project is created and external libraries are added to it while the location of those external jars are within the same project inside a folder which i created.

So when i copy the project to pendrive and import it to another system(say my friends pc's eclipse) the JRE system libraries and reference libraries are not copied along with it and I have to add them manually.

is there a way that those libraries also can be copied, so next time i just copy the project to pendrive and import to another device and start using it rightaway without adding them again?

Answer (score 0):

Don't add them as `External JARs`, just add them as `JARs`. Then, set the project's JRE system library using one of the "Execution Environment" values. This will act as a small abstraction and make the reference portable across machines.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. But there is an issue following up for what i did as you mentioned. The external Jars, I am not able to use them now. 
Is there something missing which is followed up with the above steps which you mentioned?

Comment: What do you mean by "not able to use them"?

Comment: import is not happening. 
when i add as external jars it is stored/linked in 'referenced libraries' then i enter eg: webdriver and press crtl+space then it starts showing suggestions and those i am able to import them. 
but by adding them as jars it is also showing in 'referenced libraries' then it doesn't show the suggestions and i am not able to import automatically. though i can try importing it manually. but then it will be challenging.